# Dynamic class with angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create list with ngFor and I need that the `<li>` tag has a dynamic class, beginning from hex-0 to hex-19, but I'm getting it:

```html
<ul class="hex-container">
        <li *ngFor="let total of item1;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i"></li>
        <li *ngFor="let total of item2;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i"></li>
        <li *ngFor="let total of item3;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i"></li>
        <li *ngFor="let total of item4;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i"></li>
      </ul>
      
      
      
// I got

<ul _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex-container">
    <!---->
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-0"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-1"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-2"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-3"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-4"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-5"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-6"></li>
    <!---->
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-0"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-1"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-2"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-3"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-4"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-5"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-6"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-7"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-8"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-9"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-10"></li>
    <!---->
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-0"></li>
    <li _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex hex-1"></li>
    <!---->
</ul>
```

What I have to do to get class hex-0 to hex-19 or more?

**UPDATE:** I need to put a specific class for items N1, N2, N3 and N4, like class="hex hex-0 n1", class="hex hex-1 n2", ...

Comment: What is underlying reason you need to have those CSS classes? Could an advance CSS selector be used instead? This would be much easier to pull off.

Comment: @gretro I need to set a different style for N1, N2, ...

Comment: CSS selectors may be a better option in this case.

Comment: @gretro You mean :nth-child(), :last-child and :first-child?is it the better way?

Comment: I would not bet it's the better way. It is definitely a way of achieving what you are looking for. Otherwise, you need an algorithm that allow you to calculate your index based on the group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to combine the arrays, with spread operator

in component.ts

```
  totalSquadsN1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquads = [...this.totalSquadsN1, ...this.totalSquadsN2, ...this.totalSquadsN3, ...this.totalSquadsN4];
```

in component.html

```
<ul _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex-container">
<li *ngFor="let total of totalSquads;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i">{{i}}</li>
</ul >
```

#### Updated, since question has evolved...

If you need to combine a set of arrays to one long list, but assign a specific class to each array you could go with the  forEach approach (note:  this is just one example)

```
  totalSquadsN1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquadsN4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  totalSquads = [];

  constructor() {
    let i = 1;
    let arrays = [this.totalSquadsN1, this.totalSquadsN2, this.totalSquadsN3, this.totalSquadsN4];
    arrays.forEach((array) => {
      array.forEach((instance) => {
        this.totalSquads.push({value: instance, class: 'n' + i});
      });
      i++;
    });
  }
```

Then in your html

```
<ul _ngcontent-c9="" class="hex-container">
  <li *ngFor="let total of totalSquads;let i=index" [ngClass]="'hex hex-'+ i +  ' ' +  total.class ">{{i}}</li>
</ul >
```

Comment: @ESC, yeah nevermind, *ngFor hates code, or anything not iterateable. This will have to be done in the component side. Updated answer

Comment: I like this very much.

Comment: How Can I put a specific Class for each n1, n2, n3 and n4 items? Lice class="n1", class="n2" ... ?  Updated the question.

Comment: may you show me in your answer, how can I do this? I did not understand

Comment: @ESC, did the updated answer help your updated question?

Comment: Not worked for me =/, but your first answer help me a lot =D

Comment: @ESC, shrugs, copy and pasted to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdjtam)

Comment: @ESC, no idea who added componentOne.ts, look inside App->app.component.ts, and app.component.html

Comment: I'll change somethings in my code and use your answer, thank you for help me